# magento Error " the product could not be found. " while adding product to cart from category page here product is added programatically

Tags: magento, product, cart

first of all i added a product to category suppose id 4 programmatically by `$product->save();`. Then i get id of added product also i had mentioned visibility to catalog, search and enabled true and stock is maintained.

but i call that product to add to cart by ajax request it shows error the product could not be found. please suggest me the solutions. thank you..

**my code is as below**

```
$product1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(
    Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
)->load($product->getId());

$params = array(
    'product' => $product1->getId(),
    'qty' => 1,
    'value' => $product1->getPrice()
);

try {
    print_r($product1);
    $cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();
    $cart->addProduct($product1, $params);
    $cart->save();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

the above code is to add custom product to cart.

i had checked that the product is adding successfully to the backend but error throws when adding to cart

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to quote instead,

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quote->addProduct($product, 1);
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```